# I am trying to hide form field on submitting the form and display successful message

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

AS I am new to jQuery I am trying to learn new things so I need little help in this : As I am trying to hide form field on submitting the form and display successful message but the form keep reloading and fields are not hiding.

following is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact_form").submit( function() {
     $("#contact_form").hide();
      $(".successMessage").show();
     });
});
```

```html
<section class="section NPScontainer">
  <a name="pagecontent" id="pagecontent"></a>
  <div class="container content page NPScontainer">
      <div class="feature_divider NPS-divider"></div>
    {% render 'page-multi-column', content: page.content %}

    <div class="one-whole column"> 
    <div class="rich-text__content center">
    <div class="rich-text__text featured_text">
       <h1>THANK YOU</h1>
       <p><strong>Thank you for giving us a rating</strong></p>
       <p>If you have further details to share with us regarding your rating, please don’t hesitate to share them.</p>
       <p>Your feedback will help us improve our services for you.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="successMessage">"Thank you, we value your feedback. If your feedback requires a response, our customer service team will reach out to you via the email address you have provided.”</p>
      <div class="nps_feedback_form">
      {% form 'contact' %}
        {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
        
        
        <div class="feedback-type">
        <label for="feedback-type">Feedback type</label>
        <div class="nps-radio">
        <span><input type="radio" name="contact[feedback_type]" value="Compliments" id="comments"><label for="comments">Compliments</label></span>
        <span><input type="radio" name="contact[feedback_type]" value="Areas for improvement" id="suggestions"><label for="suggestions">Areas for improvement</label></span>
        <span><input type="radio" name="contact[feedback_type]" value="Questions" id="questions"><label for="questions">Questions</label></span>
        </div>
        </div> 
      
        <div class="message">
          <label for="message">Feedback</label>
          <textarea name="contact[body]" id="message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        
        <div class="personal-info">
        <div class="first-name">
          <label for="first-name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="contact[first_name]" id="first-name" required/>
        </div>
      
        <div class="email">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="contact[email]" id="email" required />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
          <input  id="submitnpsform" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    {% endform %}
        
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: get the event and then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

The default flow for forms is reloading the page when submitting, so you need to prevent this using `event.preventDefault()`. That should stop the form from reloading the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact_form").submit( function(event) {
     event.preventDefault()
     $("#contact_form").hide();
      $(".successMessage").show();
     });
});
```

Comment: But it will submit the form right?

Comment: It depends on how you want to submit and what your expecting to happen. Usually we make a request onSubmit event, and when the request is finished show the success message, if your not using the request method you need the page to reload.

Comment: hey @leo I have tried to implement this half way its working but every time i fill the form on submit it ask for captcha and it reloads and the success Message gone, and fields are back .
Please help..
URL of page : https://betterbody.co/pages/nps-thank-you

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the code, but seems like you have something forcing a reload after onsubmit is complete. This request https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6LcCR2cUAAAAANS1Gpq_mDIJ2pQuJphsSQaUEuc9